# start a PowerShell script as local system user and redirect the script output

Tags: powershell

I need to start a PowerShell script as user "nt authority\system" and want to redirect the output of the script to a file. To start PowerShell as system user I use [PsExec.exe](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sonam_rastogi_blogs/2017/01/16/run-powershell-using-local-system-account/)
My code so fart that does work:

```
$Arguments = "-i -s Powershell.exe -File C:\temp\SetupNlb.ps1"
Start-Process "C:\temp\PsExec.exe" -Wait -ArgumentList $Arguments
```

Now the code with output redirection that doesn't work:

```
$Arguments = "-i -s Powershell.exe -File C:\temp\SetupNlb.ps1 *> C:\temp\SetupNlb.log"
Start-Process "C:\temp\PsExec.exe" -Wait -ArgumentList $Arguments
```

The problem could be that the -File parameter of Powershell.exe should be the last parameter but i think the redirection of the output/streams as well.

Comment: Redirection is a feature of the shell, not of PsExec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.  Can you do this instead?

```
C:\temp\PsExec.exe -i -s powershell.exe -Command "c:\temp\SetupN1b.ps1 *> c:\temp\SetupN1b.log"
```